# Executing korn shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, ksh

I am trying to execute my korn shell script and I ma getting error like:

```
syntax error near unexpected token '§'{\r' 'filename.ksh.
```

and the line its pointing to is this where I have made a function:

```
 function abc() {
}
```

and I tried removing this function and even then I get the same error

```
     abc(){
}
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have DOS line endings in your script; remove them.

Comment: sorry which DOS lines?

Comment: All of them, presumably. Your error message indicates the first line ends with `{\r`, not just `{`, because only the LF of the CR/LF pair is treated as terminating the line.

Comment: hi, this solves the problem in that line but in other lines as I have sql statements and they have ')' brackets at the end of line so how should I end that one. Thanks.

Comment: That's a completely different question. Don't introduce new problems into an existing question.

Comment: Try `cat your_script | tr -d '\r' > copy_of_your_script`. This will remove all CR's thereby replacing all DOS/Windows line-breaks (`\r\n` also known as `CR/LF`) with unix line-breaks (`\n` also known as `LF`). Try if the resulting file named copy_of_your_script is okay. Depending on the editor you use, hopefully it will pick up on the fact the line-breaks are unix-style line-breaks on future edits of copy_of_your_script, otherwise switch to an other editor.